# constexpr std::array with static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, static-assert, stdarray

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    constexpr const std::array<int, 2> arr {{ 0, 1 }};
    constexpr const int arr2[] = { 0, 1};

    static_assert(arr[0] == arr2[0], "asdf");
    static_assert(arr[1] == arr2[1], "asdfasdf");

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc 4.8.2` and `4.9.1` using `g++ test.cpp --std=c++11`, the compilation succeeds.
When compiled with `clang 3.4` and `3.5` using `clang++ test.cpp --std=c++11` however, the compilation fails:

```
test.cpp:8:16: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
        static_assert(arr[0] == arr2[0], "asdf");
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:8:16: note: non-constexpr function 'operator[]' cannot be used in a constant expression
```

So my question is, which compiler is "right" in the sense of being compliant with C++11? And, if `clang` is correct, then why is std::array's `operator[]` not constexpr capable? Isn't that rather one of the things that `std::array` was supposed to help resolve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `clang` is correct, [operator []](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at) is not a constexpr in C++11 but is a constexpr in C++14

```
constexpr const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const; (since C++14)
```

so compiling with `-std=c++14` should work though (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SFi736IVk0fwDTPw)*).

In the [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `23.3.2.1` *Class template array overview* has the following for `operator []`:

```
reference operator[](size_type n);
const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
```

while the [C++14 draft standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) has the following:

```
reference operator[](size_type n);
constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
^^^^^^^^^
```

**Update**

Draft standard [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) which came after C++11, contains fixes an enhancements to C++11. It contains a *constexpr* version of `operator []`. If this was part of a defect report then `gcc` would be correct and this seems plausible considering `clang 3.6.0` also accepts the program in C++11 mode.

**Update 2**

I found the document that introduced the changes, [N3470](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3470.html)  and since I can not find any defect reports on this specific issue then this seems like an enhancement and therefore should not be part of C++11.

Comment: In C++11, it became possible to declare `array::operator[] const` as `constexpr`, but the committee didn't get around to doing so until C++14. In C++14, it became possible to declare `array::operator[]` as `constexpr`...

Comment: @Casey I found the document that introduced the change into `N3485`, I added it to my answer. As far as I understand if it was considered a defect it should be allowed in C++11 mode but otherwise not. The document does not clarify that though.

Comment: I was mostly poking fun at the standard: library changes often lag behind core, because core likes to make changes at the last minute without giving library adequate time to react. I believe that the `constexpr` additions in N3470 are an enhancement, since the only defect report for `array` that involves `constexpr` is [LWG DR 720](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#720), and it doesn't involve `operator[]`.

Comment: Compiling in clang 3.4 with --std=c++1y 3.5 with --std=c++14 does indeed seem to work as I'd expect.