# Why isn't the operator[] of a std::array temporary constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, stdarray

I was stuffing some values into a `constexpr std::array` and then continuing the compile-time static goodness into more `constexpr` values when I discovered that you can't use an element as a `constexpr` initializer in C++11.

This is because `std::array::operator[]` is actually not marked `constexpr` until C++14: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741152/688724

After a compiler flag upgrade, I can now use an element of a `constexpr std::array` as a `constexpr` value:

```
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<int, 1> array{{3}};
// Initialize a constexpr from an array member through its const operator[]
// that (maybe?) returns a const int & and is constexpr
constexpr int a = array[0];  // Works in >=C++14 but not in C++11
```

But sometimes I want to use a temporary array in a `constexpr` computation, and that doesn't work.

```
// Initialize a constexpr from a temporary
constexpr int b = std::array<int, 1>{{3}}[0];  // Doesn't work!
```

I get this from clang++ 3.6 with -std=c++14:

```
prog.cc:9:15: error: constexpr variable 'b' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr int b = std::array<int, 1>{{3}}[0];  // Doesn't work!
              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:9:19: note: non-constexpr function 'operator[]' cannot be used in a constant expression
constexpr int b = std::array<int, 1>{{3}}[0];  // Doesn't work!
                  ^
/usr/local/libcxx-3.5/include/c++/v1/array:183:41: note: declared here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY reference operator[](size_type __n)             {return __elems_[__n];}
                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

What's the difference between the two variables I'm indexing into? Why can't I use a direct-initialized temporary `std::array`'s `operator[]` as `constexpr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temporary `array` in your second example is itself not `const`, so you end up calling the non-`const` `operator[]` overload, which is not `constexpr`. You can get your code to work if you first cast the `array` to `const`.

```
constexpr int b = static_cast<std::array<int, 1> const&>(std::array<int, 1>{{3}})[0];
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17b175565589e7f0)

Comment: Oh, of course! I need to play with this some more, but do you see any reason why the non-const `operator[]` shouldn't also be marked `constexpr`?

Yes, it returns a non-`const` reference but as I understand, the [C++14 rule relaxation](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#extended-constexpr) separates compile-time computation from cv-qualification.

So would there be any side effects of having this?
`constexpr reference operator[](size_type n);
constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;`

Comment: Seems to work fine: [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5856b0809e308c)

Comment: @XoWang I'm not sure what the ramifications of doing that would be. It looks like all the C++14 `constexpr` additions to member functions in the standard library have been only applied to the `const` overloads, so the intent seems to be that these functions should not mutate data members, but again, I don't know the reason why.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f8088ae04a41f3e is a prettier way -- just create the `array` directly as a `const array` instead of casting.

Comment: Now there is a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0107r0.pdf)(PDF) in the committee which allows side effects among std::array in a constexpr context including `reference operator[] (index_type)`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to @Praetorian's workaround, you can use [`std::get(std::array)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get)

```
#include<array>
int main(){
    constexpr int b = 
    //  std::array<int, 1>{{3}}[0]; // Doesn't work!
    //  static_cast<std::array<int, 1> const&>(std::array<int, 1>{{3}})[0]; // long but Works!
        std::get<0>(std::array<int, 1>{{3}});// Works!
}
```

I think `std::get` is more "agressive" than `operator[]` in producing a `constexpr`.

(Tested with `clang 3.5` and `gcc 5.0` C++14, should work with C++11)

Also, for some reason (related to the template parameter), ADL doesn't work here, so it is not possible to just write `get<0>(std::array<int, 1>{{3}})`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't use the second `array`'s `operator []` because, unlike the first `array`, the second one isn't itself a `constexpr` so you're trying to initialize `b` with a runtime value.