# Why is non-const std::array::operator[] not constexpr?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr

I'm trying to fill a 2D array on compile time with a given function. Here is my code:

```
template<int H, int W>
struct Table
{
  int data[H][W];
  //std::array<std::array<int, H>, W> data;  // This does not work

  constexpr Table() : data{}
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < H; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < W; ++j)
        data[i][j] = i * 10 + j;  // This does not work with std::array
  }
};

constexpr Table<3, 5> table;  // I have table.data properly populated at compile time
```

It works just fine, `table.data` is properly populated at compile time.

However, if I change plain 2D array `int[H][W]` with `std::array<std::array<int, H>, W>`, I have an error in the loop body:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function 'std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type& std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::operator[](std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type) [with _Tp = int; long unsigned int _Nm = 3ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::reference = int&; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type = int; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
data[i][j] = i * 10 + j;
^
Compilation failed
```

Obviously, I'm trying to call non-const overload of `std::array::operator[]`, which is not `constexpr`. The question is, why it is not `constexpr`? If C++14 allows us to modify variables declared in `constexpr` scope, why this is not supported by `std::array`?

I used to think that `std::array` is just like plain array, only better. But here is an example, where I can use plain array, but cannot use `std::array`.

Comment: Looks like an oversight in the standard.

Comment: Once you define constexpr conversion from C-style array to std::array using index std::integer_sequence idiom, it is really helpful for constexpr meta-programming in C++14.

Comment: Related to [constexpr std::array with static_assert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26741056/1708801)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, it is indeed an oversight in the standard. There even exists a proposal to fix this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0107r0.pdf

> [N3598] removed the implicit marking of constexpr member functions as const. However, the
>   member functions of std::array were not revisited after this change, leading to a surprising lack
>   of support for constexpr in std::array’s interface. This paper fixes this omission by adding
>   constexpr to the member functions of std::array that can support it with a minimal amount of
>   work.

**UPD**: Fixed in C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at

Comment: Oops. (An "oversight in the standard" is one of the worst types of oversight. Ugh. Don't they spend days upon days verifying these things?)

Comment: @JeffY Well, C++ committee mostly consists of volunteers (though first class professionals), they have only several meetings _a year_ (see https://isocpp.org/std/meetings-and-participation/upcoming-meetings). And they have to decide lots of things (e.g. see field report from Herb Sutter: http://herbsutter.com/2015/10/25/2568/). After `std::make_unique()` not being a part of C++11, I am not surprized now :)

Answer (score 11):

`std::array::operator[]` since C++14 is `constexpr` but is also `const` qualified:

```
constexpr const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const;
                                                      ^^^^^
```

Thus you have to cast the arrays to invoke the correct `operator[]` overload:

```
template<int H, int W>
struct Table
{
  //int data[H][W];
  std::array<std::array<int, H>, W> data;  // This does not work

  constexpr Table() : data{} {
    for (int i = 0; i < W; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < H; ++j)
        const_cast<int&>(static_cast<std::array<int, H> const&>(static_cast<std::array<std::array<int, H>, W> const&>(data)[i])[j]) = 10 + j;
  }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/705a77f48e476cc6)

Edit:

As opposed by some people, use of `const_cast` in such a way does not imply undefined behaviour. In fact as proposed in the proposals for the relaxation of `constexpr`, it is required by the users to do this work around with `const_cast` in order to evoke the correct subscript operator overload at least until the issue is resolved in C++17 ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341498/2352671)).

Comment: Thank for the working example, even though it does not answer my question. Looks like a hack, don't you think?

Comment: @101010 I would give the benefit of doubt and say he meant "Is it UB, or is it not?" as opposed to "Can you explain it, or not?".

Comment: @luk32 It's not UB, royalties for clarification given to Shafik Yaghmour. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341498/2352671

Comment: In fact, operations which would lead to UB are explicitly forbidden in `constexpr` context (i.e. a diagnostic is required, at least), so we can check this on multiple compilers, and if it compiles, it's not UB — unless all the checked compilers are broken.

Answer (score 6):

While my first thought was "why would you need a constexpr method on a non-const array"? ...

I then sat down and wrote a little test to see if the idea made sense:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct X{

    constexpr X()
    : _p { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 }
    {
    }

    constexpr int& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return _p[i];
    }

    int _p[10];
};

constexpr int foo()
{
    X x;
    x[3] = 4;
    return x[3];
}


auto main() -> int
{
    cout << foo() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It turns out that it does.

So I'm drawing the conclusion that the committee took the same "obvious" view that I did and discounted the idea.

Looks to me as if a proposal could be put forward to the committee to change it in c++17 - giving this question as an example.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you suggest a person to contact to propose to make a proposal? :) PS didn't you mean `return x[3]`?

Comment: Oh, it already exists! See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0107r0.pdf

Comment: @Mikhail I chose to return a different subscript just in case the optimiser decided that returning x[3] was a nop :) Whenever I'm writing these little tests in a single file I try to pre-empt the optimiser deciding that the entire program can be optimised away!

Answer (score 3):

This question intrigued me so much that I decided to figure out a solution that would allow the array to be initialised at compile time with a function that took x and y as parameters.

Presumably this could be adapted for any number of dimensions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


// function object that turns x and y into some output value. this is the primary predicate
struct init_cell_xy
{
    constexpr init_cell_xy() = default;

    constexpr int operator()(int x, int y) const
    {
        return (1 + x) * (1 + y);
    }
};

// function object that applies y to a given x
template<int X = 1>
struct init_cell_for_x
{
    constexpr init_cell_for_x() = default;

    constexpr int operator()(int y) const
    {
        return _xy(X, y);
    }

private:
    init_cell_xy _xy;
};

// an array of dimension 1, initialised at compile time
template<int Extent>
struct array1
{
    template<class F, int...Is>
    constexpr array1(F&& f, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
    : _values { f(Is)... }
    {}

    template<class F>
    constexpr array1(F&& f = init_cell_for_x<>())
    : array1(std::forward<F>(f), std::make_integer_sequence<int, Extent>())
    {}

    constexpr auto begin() const { return std::begin(_values); }
    constexpr auto end() const { return std::end(_values); }
    constexpr auto& operator[](size_t i) const {
        return _values[i];
    }

private:
    int _values[Extent];

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const array1& s)
    {
        os << "[";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (const auto& i : s) {
            os << sep << i;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        return os << " ]";
    }
};

// an array of dimension 2 - initialised at compile time
template<int XExtent, int YExtent>
struct array2
{
    template<int...Is>
    constexpr array2(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
    : _xs { array1<YExtent>(init_cell_for_x<Is>())... }
    {}

    constexpr array2()
    : array2(std::make_integer_sequence<int, XExtent>())
    {}

    constexpr auto begin() const { return std::begin(_xs); }
    constexpr auto end() const { return std::end(_xs); }
    constexpr auto& operator[](size_t i) const {
        return _xs[i];
    }

private:
    array1<YExtent> _xs[XExtent];

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const array2& s)
    {
        os << "[";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (const auto& i : s) {
            os << sep << i;
            sep = ",\n  ";
        }
        return os << " ]";
    }

};




auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;

    constexpr array2<6,6> a;

    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```